# SSAS Cube Use Windows Authentication From Asp Application

Tags: asp.net, ssas, olap-cube

I've connected a web application to an SSAS Olap Cube

The user can access the web application from their PC which is on a different server to the web app and the database,the web application has it's own server and the cube is on a different server.

The SSAS cube uses windows authentication, however, instead of picking up the login of the current user it is picking up the login of the web app server

Any Idea how to fix this so it picks up the users windows login

```
User --> Web App Server --> Cube
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the *EffectiveUserName* property from 
[MSDN's page on SSAS Connection String Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn140245.aspx). Note that the caller (i.e. your web app service) must have administrative permissions on your SSAS instance.

Another option is to [configure HTTP access for your SSAS instance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx), enable Basic Authentication, and then supply your user's domain name and password using the *User ID* and *Password* connection string properties to pass these to the SSAS instance for impersonation.